# Proper way to handle flash/display message state in React.js

Tags: reactjs

In my ReactJS application, I am using the application state to maintain the flash message to be displayed to the user, e.g. `state.msgText` and `state.msgType`, used something like:

```js
this.setState({msgText:'Flash message', msgType: 'warning'});
```

I am not sure how to handle(set/unset) the message state because of the following dilemma:

1. If I unset the state variable just after render, ReactJS might rerender again (due to change in some other prop/state variable) and this time the message will not be shown in the DOM.
2. If I don't unset the state variable, it will hang around in the state and will be shown in next screens (which is definitely not desired).

Can someone please guide me through the proper way to handle this pattern? I can think of a few hacky solutions (like using timeouts, keep listening to user actions and act accordingly), but they all seem fragile to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) lifecycle hook:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  // check for condition matches
  return true
  // else
  return false
}
```

Comment: Do you think that in order to display proper message to the user, we should block rerender (which will correctly sync the screen state).

Comment: yes, in your case, you wanted to render only props/state changes to the specific and this is the solution.

Comment: Thanks! I accept your answer. But, the code relying on `shouldComponentUpdate` might not work in the future. As per ReactJS docs page: "In the future React may treat shouldComponentUpdate() as a hint rather than a strict directive, and returning false may still result in a re-rendering of the component." Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: if so, you may still use `getDerivedStateFromProps` by the way.